# OS : Malicious process affecting other one

Tags: operating-system

I came across this question from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/intuit-interview-set-9-on-campus/), and not sure about the answer.

> Given two processes P1 and P2, in Linux OS, if P2 is malicious and gets hold of a pointer that points to the location where P1 has written its data, can P2 access this data? No encryption and security is used. How can the OS ensure that it cannot access other process’s data? (The addresses are not direct addresses but indirect addresses with the base address known only to the corresponding process.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern computer systems contain memory management hardware that allows arbitrary mapping between virtual addresses (the addresses that a user process can actually access) and physical RAM addresses.  Each process has its own individual mapping, that does not share any physical addresses with other processes (unless shared memory has been explicitly requested); accessing another process's data is therefore impossible.

Think of processes as individual books on a shelf.  If you have a particular book in hand, there is no conceivable page number you could turn to that would result in you reading a *page from a different book*...